# VBA - Need to append to the end of a line in a large text

Tags: vba, excel

I have a system where I can only read 50 column's worth of data from a table at a time. The table has 150 columns that I need to read. The table has 1 million lines.

What I have been doing so far is to read the 1st 50 columns and write all 1 millions lines to a text file.

What I need to do next, is read next block of 50 columns and append lines 1 to 1 million into the existing text file that I have already written to.

This is where I become stuck. I'm not sure how I can write to a specific line in the text file. I was hoping not to have to loop each line in the existing text file to get to the row I need to append to. Is there a way to specify the line I need to append to without having to loop the text file to find the correct row?

Comment: why don't you just use the export functionalities of ms office? you could just export your table to csv file for example

Comment: Because excel has a limit on the number of lines.

Comment: What exactly is the "system" you're reading from?

Comment: A bespoke mainframe applications we had built

Comment: maybe this discussion will help you - http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/819484-access-table-text-file-csv-tab-etc-there-easy-way-do

Comment: If each line is unique, read first 50 columns and 1 million records. Write them to a file. Read next 50 columns and 1 million records. Loop through the file (million lines) and append to it. Repeat one more time. If you are familiar with SQLite, you can create prepared statements and write to that database. It might be faster with primary key indexed.

Comment: @pony2deer i'm using excel not access

Comment: since you want to do it in vba, it will be the same strategy

Comment: @pony2deer it's not because access can hold many more lines

Comment: so how are you writing the first 50 lines into a text file, supply the code and we can work on it

Comment: I read and then write as I get each line. The link you provided is suggesting a load in a table before I export it. Excel would not let me store all the date before I export it.

Comment: Can you show how you are reading the data? How do you import?

Comment: Are you able to query each set of fifty columns in the exact same row order?

Answer (score 0):

I would use SQL OLEDB and simply output data using RecordSet. Might take some time but should work. Try using `LIMIT` and `FETCH` in a loop in case the result won't load in a single go. Alternatively add a loop to the SQL statement and fetch records higher lower then a specific row ID (if your records ID is a numeric not a hash) e.g. `WHERE ID > [OLD_ID] and ID <= [OLD_ID] + 100`

### Using SQL OLEDB and RecordSet

```
Dim fileName As String, textData As String, textRow As String, fileNo As Integer
fileNo = FreeFile

Open fileName For Output As #fileNo

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
sConn = "OLEDB;Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & _
                serverInstance & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & _
                ";User ID=" & userId & ";Password=" & password & ";"
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [table_name] "
rs.Open strSQL, strcon, 3, 3
rs.MoveFirst
Do
   textData = ""
   textData = textData & ";" & rs("Col1")
   textData = textData & ";" &  rs("Col2")
   textData = textData & ";" &  rs("Col3") & vbNewLine
   Print #fileNo, textData
   rs.MoveNext
Loop Until rs.EOF

Close #fileNo
```